# Is it possible to change color current Yaxis line?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

Is it possible to change the color of a specific y-axis line using HighchartJs ?

like this for Yaxis 150 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts offers a wide range of customizations. The reference to a grid line can be found in for example `load` event and color can be changed by `attr` method.

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        this.yAxis[0].ticks[150].gridLine.attr({
          stroke: 'red'
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z59od8g2/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr